# Unable to access process running on dfferent user space in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have deployed my nodejs app in Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine (instance-1), while logged in as user `user1`. I installed all the required modules and I ran `pm2` on the instance. My site is working fine.

I have another user who has access to that instance. When the other user tried to restart the `pm2` process he is not able to access the `pm2` process running on `user1`'s user space. How to resolve this problem so that both the users can modify the process and resources running on the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the other user have the proper IAM permission on the VM instance? I believe they will need either the `Instance Admin (v1)` or `Compute Admin` role. Check here for more info about [IAM roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/#predefined_roles_matrix).

Comment: Have given Compute Instance Admin Permission to user 2. But still user2 is not able to perform "pm2 list". pm2 process was run from user1 space. when user 2 tried pm2 list its showing empty

Comment: can you tell more about the "user space" and pm2 list process? How are the users in different spaces and what does the process execute? How can I reproduce this scenario?

Comment: ssh as user1 to the instance. install pm2 run node server through pm2 as pm2 start nodeapp. then ssh into the isntance as user2. pm2 list is not showing up the nodeapp.

Comment: found this, your question seems to be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178443/how-to-run-pm2-so-other-server-users-are-able-to-access-the-process

Comment: Thank yo for ur help. Got it