# PM2 Node js service is not accessing SSH Keys (git)

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, pm2

I have created a nodejs service that uses https://github.com/steveukx/git-js package.

When launching my service with `node index.js`; everything works fine.

When using PM2 ( https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to launch my service I always got the following issue

```
57| | Permission denied (publickey).
57| | fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
57| | Please make sure you have the correct access rights
57| | and the repository exists.
```

For info; I have setted up an SSH connection from my VPS to GITHUB.
My ssh keys are on ~/.ssh/

I assume that PM2 does not access properly to my directory but I still can not figure out how to configure it.

Any help will be much appreciated; 
Regards,
Alex

Comment: any clue will be really usefull please.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few parameters that you need to use when generating the pm2 init script

```sh
$ pm2 --help | grep -i user
    -u --user <username>                             define user when generating startup script
$ pm2 --help | grep -i home
    --hp <home path>                                 define home path when generating startup script
```

So once you set these parameter while generating your init script, the problem should not come

**References:**

[How to run pm2 so other server users are able to access the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178443/how-to-run-pm2-so-other-server-users-are-able-to-access-the-process)

[How do you use pm2 startup with a non-root user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587388/how-do-you-use-pm2-startup-with-a-non-root-user)